# Linux/Bluez: Bluetooth keyboard cannot be added, getting strange "file not found" error from bluetoothd

Tags: linux, bluetooth, arch-linux

I originally paired my bluetooth keyboard using the gnome-3.12 gui, and after a recent update (archlinux) it stopped working. I unpaired the keyboard and now can't get it to pair again. When I scan for devices, it shows up briefly and then immediately disappears. I've also tried pairing from cmdline using bluetoothctl with no luck.

Running btmon during the scan process shows [this output](http://sprunge.us/aAjV). Of interest is the following:

```
< ACL Data TX: Handle 12 flags 0x00 dlen 16                                              [hci0] 24.073197
      L2CAP: Connection Response (0x03) ident 7 len 8
        Destination CID: 65
        Source CID: 67
        Result: Connection refused - security block (0x0003)
        Status: No further information available (0x0000)
```

I'm not sure what's causing the "security block". There's another strange error coming from bluetoothd (when using the --debug flag), `Refusing input device connect: No such file or directory (2)`. Here's the full bluetoothd output during the time the keyboard is turned on:

```
bluetoothd[8708]: src/adapter.c:connected_callback() hci0 device 28:37:37:2A:BC:7A connected eir_len 5
bluetoothd[8708]: src/device.c:device_create() dst 28:37:37:2A:BC:7A
bluetoothd[8708]: src/device.c:device_new() address 28:37:37:2A:BC:7A
bluetoothd[8708]: src/device.c:device_new() Creating device /org/bluez/hci0/dev_28_37_37_2A_BC_7A
bluetoothd[8708]: src/device.c:btd_device_set_temporary() temporary 1
bluetoothd[8708]: src/adapter.c:adapter_connect_list_remove() device /org/bluez/hci0/dev_28_37_37_2A_BC_7A is not on the list, ignoring
bluetoothd[8708]: src/device.c:device_set_class() /org/bluez/hci0/dev_28_37_37_2A_BC_7A 0x002540
bluetoothd[8708]: profiles/input/server.c:connect_event_cb() Incoming connection from 28:37:37:2A:BC:7A on PSM 17
bluetoothd[8708]: profiles/input/device.c:input_device_set_channel() idev (nil) psm 17
bluetoothd[8708]: Refusing input device connect: No such file or directory (2)
bluetoothd[8708]: profiles/input/server.c:confirm_event_cb()
bluetoothd[8708]: Refusing connection from 28:37:37:2A:BC:7A: unknown device
bluetoothd[8708]: src/adapter.c:dev_disconnected() Device 28:37:37:2A:BC:7A disconnected, reason 3
bluetoothd[8708]: src/adapter.c:adapter_remove_connection()
bluetoothd[8708]: src/adapter.c:adapter_remove_connection() Removing temporary device /org/bluez/hci0/dev_28_37_37_2A_BC_7A
bluetoothd[8708]: src/device.c:device_remove() Removing device /org/bluez/hci0/dev_28_37_37_2A_BC_7A
bluetoothd[8708]: src/device.c:btd_device_unref() Freeing device /org/bluez/hci0/dev_28_37_37_2A_BC_7A
bluetoothd[8708]: src/device.c:device_free() 0xedcae0
bluetoothd[8708]: plugins/policy.c:disconnect_cb() reason 3
bluetoothd[8708]: src/adapter.c:bonding_attempt_complete() hci0 bdaddr 28:37:37:2A:BC:7A type 0 status 0xe
bluetoothd[8708]: src/adapter.c:resume_discovery()
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this was all simply due to the fact that I was not following the correct steps for pairing the wireless keyboard. The button needed to be held down for much longer to re-set everything. Unfortunately all the bluetooth errors were very misleading.